# Scroll view at same time that ListView is scrolling

Tags: android, android-listview, android-scrollview

I have a RelativeLayout with a ListView and a custom View. I set the size of the custom view as the size of the ListView programatically. So I have the custom view on top of the ListView with both the same size. Obviously the ListView is not scrolling because the onTouchListener is on the customView. How can I make both scroll at the same time?

Comment: I believe there is an attribute to make a view ignore all touch events, non-focusable? I can't remember the exact name though, look at the docs

Comment: return false in *onTouch()* method, to pass the event to the ListView

Comment: I don't want to ingore all touch event, I want to make both, listview and my custom view scroll at the same time when the user try to scroll the listview.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

At the end I created a function in my custom view class with the ListView and the number of rows as parameters. Inside the view I setOnScrollListener to the ListView and I assign the position of my ListView while scrolling to my global scroll variable of the custom view. Like this

```
public void setListView(final TwoWayView listView, int totalListRows) {
    totalColumns = totalListRows;
    for (int i = 0; i < totalColumns; i++) {
        listViewItemHeights.put(i,  (int) getResources().getDimension(R.dimen.column_width));
    }
    listView.setOnScrollListener(new TwoWayView.OnScrollListener() {

        @Override
        public void onScrollStateChanged(TwoWayView view, int scrollState) {

        }

        @Override
        public void onScroll(TwoWayView view, int firstVisibleItem,
                int visibleItemCount, int totalItemCount) {
            c = listView.getChildAt(0);
            if (c != null) {
                int oldScrollX = scrollX;
                scrollX = -c.getLeft();


                for (int i = 0; i < listView.getFirstVisiblePosition(); ++i) {
                    if (listViewItemHeights.get(i) != null) {
                        scrollX += listViewItemHeights.get(i);
                    } 

                }
                scrollBy(scrollX - oldScrollX, 0);
            } 

        }
    });


}
```